# Pulling Ipad xib into universal App

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, ipad, xib

I am making a universal app that originally was going to be just iphone so I am converting the xib files into ipad xib files though I don't know how to call them

I have looked around and this is what I have found though I haven't got a clue of how to use it:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[LSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LSViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[LSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LSViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have mentioned is right..

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    self.viewController = [[LSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LSViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
} else {
    self.viewController = [[LSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LSViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
```

}

You have to create 2 xib(UI) files one for iPhone and 2nd for iPad the class name for both will be same.

In the above code LSViewController_iPhone is for iPhone and LSViewController_iPad for iPad.
Now, the given if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) condition checks for the device type and load xib file accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is very simple. if you use two separated xib for ipad and iphone, then just use a suffix **~ipad** for ipad, and use just base-name for iphone on your xib file name. example: **LSViewController.xib** for iphone xib and **LSViewController~ipad.xib** for ipad xib. The OS will automatically load the required xib based on the current device(iphone/ipad). You need not to write a single line code for loading the xib for universal app. Hope you already changed to "Universal" on "Devices" category under "Summary" tab of your app target.